# C# Windows Form Logic in passing data

Tags: c#

I need your help in applying some logic on a scenario like this: I've got the form A with text,combo,etc at the end of the form there is a button. When the user click the button it does trigger an insert into SQL as Insert into Table values (text1,text2...etc). In the same button I close the Form1 and open the Form2 that retrieves all the information by a select a,b,c,d..from Table1 where id=(select max(id) from Table1). At the end of the Form2 another button with an update on the field upd so Update Table1 set Upd=1 where id=(select max(id) from Table1). And so the user goes to the final form (same concept, taking the max(id)). It works, but only one user per time. WIth multi users triggering the button at the same time it cbecome a mess. I was thinking to take the user name from somewhere (it is a internal form in my network so the user do not insert any login or password). Which variable could I use? Ip? Many Thanks

Comment: You could look into using Windows Authentication. This can be used to identify users by their username on the network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string userName = System.Environment.UserName;
```